# Postgres 9.1 query fast second time

Tags: postgresql

Postgres version: PostgreSQL 9.1.14 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit

- Open psql and run query. Takes 80ms.
- Run same query again. Takes 11ms
- Close psql and open again.
- Running same query again results in 80ms first time and 11ms second time.

We are using pgbouncer with Transaction pooling mode.
Same behavior is observed from Java application code.

Only difference is seen in bitmap index scan times.

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on TABLE_NAME_MASKED  (cost=5.09..304.74 rows=79 width=638) (actual time=5.070..83.190 rows=105 loops=1)

Bitmap Heap Scan on TABLE_NAME_MASKED  (cost=5.09..304.74 rows=79 width=638) (actual time=2.161..12.129 rows=105 loops=1)
```

Will changing pooling mode of pgbouncer help here?
We usually see 8 TCP connections established between JVM and pgbouncer, so we hope application is not closing and opening psql session.

Any pointers to bring down execution times to 10ms level for most of the queries in production?

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: You're probably hitting query cache, which gets cleared when you close psql.

Comment: psql session was just an example, but this behavior is seen from java application also, which we believe, is not closing and opening a session every time. Only thing between java application and DB port 5432 is pgbouncer in session pooling mode.

Comment: What you see in the query plan is the time the _database_ engine needs for fetching the data.  Not pooler/netwoek traffic/else is calculated.  That suggests that your data falls out of the cache very quickly, or you have a pattern that we don't see from the question - like a `WHERE` clause that is (sufficiently) different only on the third try (I mean every pair hitting the already visited data pages).

Comment: "application is not closing and opening psql session" the session is already established in psql before you run the first query so connection overhead can't account for the difference. As others have suggested it is likely caching that is the difference. When you reconnect psql you are perhaps connecting to a different backend.

Comment: Correction: We are using transaction pooling mode, and not session. Checking if changing that will make any difference.

Comment: In your example, are you connecting psql through pgbouncer, or bypassing it and going directly to the database?

Comment: psql is also going through bouncer, but it may not make much difference if we change pooling mode to session, since closing psql means  client disconnected. But java application might benefit from mode=session, since it keeps connection open for a longer time.